# How can you find the name of the file that called a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, stack-trace

Is there a nice, recommended way to get the name of the file that called a method?  I don't want to pass `__FILE__` every time.  The closest thing I've found is taking the first element of `Kernel.caller`, which is okay but has the calling line number appended like `"test.rb:7"`.  It's easy enough to strip off, but using it seems like something that might be dependent on the interpreter or might change in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby 2.0+ you can do this using [`Kernel#caller_locations`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations). It's very similar to `caller`, with the added benefit that you don't need to parse out the file name manually, since it returns [`Thread::Backtrace::Location`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html) objects instead of `String`s:

`file1.rb`:

```
def some_method
  puts caller_locations.first.path
end
```

`file2.rb`:

```
require_relative './file1'

some_method
```

Shell:

```
$ ruby file2.rb
file2.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's safer than you think? I found this other post http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2787 where someone did something similar to what you're suggesting...

Comment: Four years later and this behavior still hasn't changed, so yes, maybe you can count on it: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-caller